# Handle onclick of a layout resource file which does not have any java file

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, onclicklistener

I am working with google places api json to retrieve the nearby hotels in a listview, I have successfully done that but I also want to click a button present in the listview itms to go to the google maps.As the list view items are shown from a layout resource file without any java code, how should I handle the onclick event of a button in that layout resource file ? 
I tried to create an activity separately to handle the events of that layout resource file but that dosen't work, it shows->

And my layout resource file is->

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout

        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/linlayout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:src="@drawable/map"
           android:layout_width="45dp"
           android:layout_height="45dp"
           android:layout_gravity="right"
           />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name : "
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="value"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/nm"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and The onclick habdler java code is->

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity {
    Double lat=22.2254,lang=53.2354;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final  View vw=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        final Context context=vw.getContext();

    ImageView imgv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        imgv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("ListItem","This Onclick worked ok");
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapView.class);
                intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
                intent.putExtra("lang",lang);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

It is not working..
Please help me find a way so that If I click the image view with id "map"-it takes me to another activity!!

Here is the listview adapter->

```
public class hotelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hotels> {
public hotelAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Hotels> hotelsList) {
    super(context,0,hotelsList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Hotels hotels=getItem(position);
    Context context;

    if(convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

    }

//    context=convertView.getContext();

    TextView namevw=convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
    TextView rtingvw=convertView.findViewById(R.id.rtng);
    TextView adrsvw=convertView.findViewById(R.id.adrs);

    namevw.setText(hotels.getName());
    rtingvw.setText(hotels.getRating());
    adrsvw.setText(hotels.getVicinity());

    return convertView;
    // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
}
```

and the OnCreate of MainActivity.java->

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvw);

    Intent intent=getIntent();



    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final  View vw=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
    ImageView imgv=(ImageView) vw.findViewById(R.id.map);

    imgv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("ListItem","This Onclick worked ok");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tHIS WORKED YEAH!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `MapView.Class` what is this is it activity?

Comment: MapView.class just shows a normal activity with maps @R2R

Comment: where is your main activity, listview and adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello You can resolve your problem with simple way like this..

**MainActivity**

```
    hotelAdapter hotel;
    ArrayList<Hotels> hotelsList;
    ListView  listView;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        hotelsList=new ArrayList<>();
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvw);
         hotel = new hotelAdapter(MainActivity.this, hotelsList);
         listView.setAdapter(hotel);

    }
```

**Adapter Class**

```
      public class hotelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hotels> {

        Double lat = 22.2254, lang = 53.2354;
        Context context=null;

        public hotelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Hotels> hotelsList) {
            super(context, 0, hotelsList);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            Hotels hotels = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

    context=convertView.getContext();   //ReEdited to make the code work
            TextView namevw = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
            TextView rtingvw =(TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.rtng);
            TextView adrsvw =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adrs);
            ImageView map = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.map); // edited
            namevw.setText(hotels.getName());
            rtingvw.setText(hotels.getRating());
            adrsvw.setText(hotels.getVicinity());

            map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
                    intent.putExtra("lang", lang);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return convertView;
            // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Surely I HAVE UPVOTED, IF YOU COULD UPVOTE MY QUESTION..@Dileep Patel ..that would be great

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this:

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final  View vw=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        final Context context=vw.getContext();

        ImageView imgv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        imgv.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("ListItem","This Onclick worked ok");
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapView.class);
            intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
            intent.putExtra("lang",lang);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Comment: Firstly the code you gave is wrong..and secondly I already removed the mapvw method from my question...I am not using onclick in the xml

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

```
android:onClick="mapvw"
```

from layout .
then it will work fine.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove that here-I HAD TRIED TO REMOVE THAT IN THE CODE-Still it did not work!!

Comment: but the error u posted " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method mapvw(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'map'"

is because of this.
can u post the latest error please?

Comment: It dose not show any error in the logcat when using onclicklistener-but it still dosenot work @R2R

Comment: implements OnClickListener next to the activity

Answer (score 0):

When you defining attribute `android:onClick`, you also need to add the method which will be called by it.

Because you are using `android:onClick="mapvw"` then you need to add the following code to your activity:

```
public void mapvw(View view) {
  // Do related to the view.
}
```

Comment: I am not using mapvw-that was a typing mistake..How can I use such an onclick which layout resource dose not have a backend code...so I have to use the setONCLICKLISTENER

Comment: what are you really trying to do? Did you want to start activity in when you clicking an item of list view?

Comment: YES  I am trying to start an activity on click of the mageview

Comment: try removing this, because you don't need it: `LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final  View vw=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        final Context context=vw.getContext();`

Comment: Then change `Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapView.class);` to `Intent intent=new Intent(ListItem.this,MapView.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to implement `onclick`of any `View` or `ViewGroup`:

**WAY: 1**

Have `onclick` attribute in your xml as:

```
android:onClick="doSomething"
```

and have a method in associated activity as:

```
public void doSomething(View view){
    // do something
}
```

**WAY: 2**

Programatically set `OnClickListener`:

By passing OnClickListener as object:

```
imgv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

Or have the activity implement `OnClickListener` interface as:

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final  View vw=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        final Context context=vw.getContext();

        ImageView imgv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        imgv.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("ListItem","This Onclick worked ok");
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapView.class);
            intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
            intent.putExtra("lang",lang);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
  ImageView imgv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map);

  imgv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

 Toast.makeText(ListItem.this, "You clicked on ImageView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
 });
```

Comment: How can I write this -> Toast.makeText(ListItem.this, "You clicked on ImageView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
?as the layout is not a part of any activity..

Comment: your question is not clear to me, can you please explain little more

Comment: Actually listitem.java and listitem.xml are 2 separate files -not asssociated like other single activities. A listview is on the activity_main.xml and that listview is populated by the list_itm.xml contents --so how can i manage the onclick of such a layout?

Comment: I have tried placing onclick on MainActivity.java and ListItem.java but none of them worked!!

Comment: did u try interface...??

Comment: No,how can i do that?